# popup in sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

i am using ajax modal popup in sharepoint, but the assembly references some are missing and if i am trying to put those assembly references, the page is going to error page. Is there any other alternative other than using ajax control popup in sharepoint. I want to show popup badly in my current project. Please help me regarding this

Comment: how are you trying to put those assembly references? Or also how are you trying to create the ajax modal? webpart, custom control, etc...

Comment: AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.5.40412.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' uses 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'  
This was the error

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the version of .NET you're using in your project. I think AjaxControlToolkit uses v 3.5?

Comment: ya. ajaxcontroltool kit is usning v3.5.0.0, i added the necessary assemblies in the web.config file of the site. even though it hsows the error

Comment: Is there any other alternatives other than ajax popups?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use commonShowModalDialog() which is used by SharePoint by default. Here is a sample snippet

```
//Opens the popup window
function openPopup()
{
    commonShowModalDialog("/_layouts/samplepage.aspx", "resizable: yes; status:no; scroll: no; help: no; center: yes; dialogwidth:410px; dialogHeight:300px;", callback);
}

//callback function to retrieve any values from popup
function callback(ret)
{
    alert(ret);
}
```

To return a value from the popup use `window.returnValue`. Hope it helps.